# binary sequence subsum combinations

Tags: string, algorithm, combinations, permutation, sequences

Given a sequence `a1a2....a_{m+n}` with `n` +1s and `m` -1s, if for any `1=< i <=m+n`, we have
`sum(ai) >=0`, i.e.,

```
a1 >= 0
a1+a2>=0
a1+a2+a3>=0
...
a1+a2+...+a_{m+n}>=0
```

then the number of sequence that meets the requirement is `C(m+n,n) - C(m+n,n-1)`, where the first item is the total number of sequence, and the second term refers to those sub-sum < 0.

I was wondering whether there is a similar formula for the bi-side sequence number :

```
a1 >= 0
a1+a2>=0
a1+a2+a3>=0
...
a1+a2+...+a_{m+n}>=0 
a_{m+n}>=0
a_{m+n-1}+a_{m+n}>=0
...
a1+a2+...+a_{m+n}>=0
```

I feel like it can be derived similarly with the single-side subsum problem, but the number `C(m+n,n) - 2 * C(m+n,n-1)` is definitely incorrect. Any ideas ?

Comment: Some sequences are doubly excluded. This question would fit better on the Mathematics Stack Exchange (migration is too slow, so repost there and delete this one).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about combinatorics, not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clue: the first case is a number of paths (with +-1 step) from (0,0) to (n+m, n-m) point, where path never falls below zero line. (Like Catalan numbers for parenthesis pairs, but without balance requirement n=2m)
[image]
Desired formula is a number of (+-1) paths which never rise above (n-m) line. It is possible to get recursive formulas. I hope that compact formula exists for it.

If we consider lattice path at nxm grid, where horizontal step for +1 and vertical step for -1, then we need a number of paths restricted by parallelogramm with (n-m) base

[image]